# Eclipse Neon 1.RC3 Package crashing on 64-bit Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-neon

I recently downloaded `Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers`([Eclipse Neon 1.RC3 Package](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/Neon/1.RC3)) for Linux 64 bit as I am using Ubuntu 14.04LTS 64-bit.
Every time I launch eclipse, it simply crashes. The only plug-in I downloaded after the eclipse download was ZK Studio from eclipse marketplace.

## Eclipse error log:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f723c885868, pid=4242, tid=0x00007f723df7c700
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_101-b13) (build 1.8.0_101-b13)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.101-b13 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [libjvm.so+0x4f0868]  ConstantPool::klass_name_at(int)+0x28
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#
```

Link to the complete error log is [here](https://pastebin.com/g32xd7zY).

## Configurations:

[image]

## Question:

How do I prevent eclipse from crashing?

Comment: Check this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/457506/eclipse-adt-crash-failed-to-write-core-dump-core-dumps-have-been-disabled

Comment: For a start you should move to the release version of Neon. The release is based on RC4.

Comment: @greg-449 - If I understand you correctly, do you mean I should use RC4? Has it been released yet?

Comment: I am not sure where greg is getting at. I think RC3 is the current latest greatest that one could be using.

Comment: No, you should use the actual release version of Neon. The release version is the same as RC4a which is newer than the RC3 you are using).

Comment: @GhostCat The release version of Neon is based on RC4a, RC3 is older and there were fixes after that.

Comment: Interestingly enough, I only found pages for RC3. But on the other hand, it seems to get harder and harder to identify the "correct" package/setup to download from eclipse.org in the first place.

Comment: I think I downloaded the [Neon release version](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/Neon/RC3) from the eclipse download page for Linux 64-bit. If you are referring to some other download link, can you please share the download link here?

Comment: @GhostCat Actually, my mistake, this is talking about 4.6.1 which has not been released yet. There was an RC3 but that has now been updated to RC4.

Comment: Yes, my mistake, they seem to be pushing release candidate builds of 4.6.1 on the Packages downloads - not sure I agree with that. Ignore my earlier remarks.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
./eclipse -clean
```

and if this is not enough, try:

```
./eclipse -clean -clearPersistedState
```

Comment: Helped in my case. Last running instance was killed so workspace wasn`t closed correctly.

Answer (score 1):

First, use the Neon release from http://eclipse.org/downloads . Then if it still fails, it may brme because Ubuntu uses a modified version of GTK3 on 14.04 that has issues with Eclipse IDE. If problem persist with the Neon release, try `SWT_GTK3=0 ./eclipse`

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled JDK and reinstalled JDK from system. Then Eclipse started working again fine.